# Password input rules

Tags: java, passwords

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise6_18 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Password rules:\n"
            + "Password must have at least eight characters\n"
            + "Password must consist of only letters and digits\n"
            + "Password must contain at least two digits\n"
            + "Enter a password:");
    String pWT = sc.next();
    passWordIsValid(pWT);
    }
    public static void passWordIsValid (String password) {
        boolean passWordIsValid;

        if (password.length() < 8) {
            passWordIsValid = false;
            }
        else if (password.indexOf(0) == -1 && password.indexOf(1) == -1
                && password.indexOf(2) == -1 && password.indexOf(3) == -1
                && password.indexOf(4) == -1 && password.indexOf(5) == -1
                && password.indexOf(6) == -1 && password.indexOf(7) == -1
                && password.indexOf(8) == -1 && password.indexOf(9) == -1) {
                passWordIsValid = false;
        }
        else 
            passWordIsValid = true;     

        if (passWordIsValid == true) 
            System.out.print("Password is valid");
        else if (passWordIsValid == false) 
            System.out.println("Password is invalid");      
    }   
}
```

I am trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter a password that is at least 8 characters long, contains at least two digits and is comprised of only letters and digits but when I enter: password12 it says password is invalid. P.S. I know I haven't added the requirement for at least two digits in the method.

Comment: Try `password.indexOf("0") == -1 ....`. You want to look for the String  `0`, not the codepoint `0`

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe I didn't notice that!

Comment: Also, try going through the algorithm by hand and you will find the error in logic in your first else-block in passwordIsValid().If your password contains  a "1", then index("1") will return a positive number and thus the test will be false.

Comment: Suppose passowrd is > 8 characters such as `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP12` or `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP12#`.  Consider using a loop to check each character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use `Regex`, you can use a simple `for loop` and `if statement`, you may do something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PromptPassword {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Password rules:\n"
                            + "Password must have at least eight characters\n"
                            + "Password must consist of only letters and digits\n"
                            + "Password must contain at least two digits\n"
                            + "Enter a password:");
        String pWT = sc.nextLine(); //read the entire line
        passWordIsValid(pWT.trim()); // to remove leading spaces (if any)
    }   
    public static void passWordIsValid (String password) {
        boolean passWordIsValid = true;
        int noOfDigits =0;


        if (password.length() > 8) { // if it's less than 8 chars -> no need to continue
            for(char c : password.toCharArray()){
                if(Character.isDigit(c)){ // if it's a digit, increment
                    noOfDigits++;
                }
                else if(!Character.isAlphabetic(c)){ // if it's not a digit nor alphapet
                    passWordIsValid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

         if (passWordIsValid && noOfDigits>=2){
             System.out.print("Password is valid");
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("Password is invalid"); 
         }

    }
}
```

**Test**

```
Enter a password: abcd12     ->  Password is invalid (less than 8)
Enter a password: abcde@123  ->  Password is invalid (contains special char)
Enter a password: abcdefghi1 ->  Password is invalid (less than 2 digits)
Enter a password: abcdefg12  ->  Password is valid (9 in length and contains 2 digits and no special chars)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...else if (password.indexOf(0) == -1 && password.indexOf(1) == -1
            && password.indexOf(2) == -1 && password.indexOf(3) == -1
            && password.indexOf(4) == -1 && password.indexOf(5) == -1
            && password.indexOf(6) == -1 && password.indexOf(7) == -1
            && password.indexOf(8) == -1 && password.indexOf(9) == -1) {
            passWordIsValid = false;
    }...
```

What are you trying to achieve with this code? It doesn't make any sense at all. You probably want to loop over every character of the string instead while counting for every character if it is a digit (and you could "break;" out of the loop as soon as your count is >=2).

Also: Don't save passwords in strings... they will stay in the string pool for quite a while and can be read from memory by malicious programs. You can use a char[] instead.

Comment: Not a great answer, but at least going in a better direction than all the others...

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm will not check whether there are at least two digits, and will not check that there are only printable characters and digits in it. Instead of checking for indexOf() you need to loop through all of the characters and count the number that are digits, and ensure each one is either a digit or an alphabetic character, keeping track of the number that are digits.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex to validate password. positive Lookahead does very good job at validating strings.

Example in java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String passwd = "aaZZa44@"; 
    String pattern = "^(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$";
  System.out.println(passwd.matches(pattern));
```

}

```
(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9]) at least 2 digits.
(?=.*[a-z]) lower case a-z
(?=.*[A-Z]) upper case A-Z
{8,} 8 digit in length
```

Comment: Thanks that works way better than what I was thinking

Comment: you welcome you may play around with that regex so include different modifiers.

Comment: So I tried this in an if statement and it works except for when I only use lowercase characters. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes if you only want lowercase password you can take out (?=.*[A-Z]) and that should pass with 2 digit lowercase letter and at least 8 character long

Comment: Also I can refer you to this website where you can test this regex https://regex101.com/ where you can quickly test the regex

Comment: @Will. O Please accept the Answer if it catered to your Question. Thanks